# How do I ensure that certain RVM-managed executables are always available?

Tags: ruby, rvm

If I install an executable command that is distributed as a Rubygem, and I do it under an RVM-managed environment, these executables  disappear from my PATH if I `cd` in and out of directories with a `.rvmrc` file that switches the Ruby environment.

How can I ensure that certain Rubygem executables are always available, short of installing the gem in every single one of my rvm environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use wrappers: https://rvm.io/integration/cron/

to get "global" gist:

```
rvm 1.9.3 do gem install gist
rvm wrapper 1.9.3 --no-prefix gist
```

now you can use gist command in any ruby

Answer (score 0):

You can install the gem into the default or global gemset.